# How do I read data from one HTML file and display it in another with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one HTML file that contains a table with items and their price. I successfully got the javascript working to traverse the table and calculate the sum of the prices, but only when it's inside the same html file. I would like to display this calculation in a separate html file and I'm having trouble doing so.

```
//testTable.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Html Table</h2>

<table id="EstoreTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Quantity</th> 
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>iPhone X</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>299.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple Watch 3</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>250.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>MacBook Pro 13" </td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1199.99</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    <a href="assign1_agm75_checkout.html" target="_blank" id="checkout">Checkout</a>
    <script src="ShoppingAmount.js"></script>
    </body>  

</html>
```

```
//ShoppingAmount.js

function getCheckoutAmounts()
{ 
    var table = document.getElementById('EstoreTable'); //data from TestTable.html
    var sum = 0,
        taxTotal = 0,
        tax = .0825,
        shipping = 5.99,
        due = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
        {
           sum = sum + parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML); //stores total price into sum
        }

    taxTotal = tax * sum; //stores calculated tax

    due = sum + taxTotal + shipping;

    // SET VIA query string
    this.href += "?sum=" + sum;
    this.href += "?taxTotal=" + taxTotal;
    this.href += "?shipping=" + shipping;
    this.href += "?due=" + due;

    // SET SUM VIA localStorage
    window.localStorage.setItem("sum", sum);
    window.localStorage.setItem("taxTotal", taxTotal);
    window.localStorage.setItem("shipping", shipping);
    window.localStorage.getItem("due", due);

}

document.querySelector("#checkout").addEventListener("click", getCheckoutAmounts);
```

```
//Checkout.html

<html>
<h1>Checkout</h1>

Total Shopping Amount: $<span id="Shopamount"></span><br>

Total Tax: $<span id="TaxTotal"></span><br>

Total Shipping Charges: $<span id= "charges"></span><br>

Total Amount Due: $<span id="total"></span><br>
<script>

    // GET data VIA localStorage
    document.querySelector("#Shopamount").textContent = window.localStorage.getItem("sum");
    document.querySelector("#TaxTotal").textContent = window.localStorage.getItem("taxTotal");
    document.querySelector("#charges").textContent = window.localStorage.getItem("shipping");
    document.querySelector("#total").textContent = window.localStorage.getItem("due");


    // GET SUM VIA query string
    let queryString = document.location.search;
    let sum = queryString.split("=")[1];
    let taxTotal = queryString.split("=")[1];
    let shipping = queryString.split("=")[1];
    let due = queryString.split("=")[1];

    document.querySelector("#Shopamount").textContent = sum;
    document.querySelector("TaxTotal").textContent = taxTotal;
    document.querySelector("charges").textContent = shipping;
    document.querySelector("total").textContent = due;
</script>
```

The goal is to get it to print in Checkout.html but I've been at this for hours with no results. please help.
[UPDATE]: After some help from @Kostax, I managed to get some of the calculations displayed, but it's mixed with some bugs.

Comment: Have you considered using cookies or localStorage to store the calculated value and access it from different pages? FYI here's the localStorage docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: How are you planning to redirect the user, once you have the table values calculated?

Comment: @KostasX the pages are linked through a homepage. The table is acting as the shopping cart

Comment: How does the table gets updated? @Asa Murphy

Answer (score -1):

Here's a basic setup to get you started. The JS in testTable, calculates the total, once the Checkout button is clicked and stores the sum in localStorage. The link then gets triggered and redirects you to the checkout page, where the sum value is retrieved from localStorage and displayed in the page.

**testTable.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        table,
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <h2>Html Table</h2>

    <table id="EstoreTable" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>iPhone X</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>299.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Apple Watch 3</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>250.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MacBook Pro 13" </td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1199.99</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="Checkout.html" target="_blank" id="checkout">Checkout</a>
    <script src="ShoppingAmount.js"></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

**ShoppingAmount.js**:

```
function getShoppingAmount(e) {

    var table = document.getElementById('EstoreTable'); //data from TestTable.html
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML); //stores total price into sum
    }

    // SET SUM VIA query string
    this.href += "?sum=" + sum; 

    // SET SUM VIA localStorage
    window.localStorage.setItem( "sum", sum );

}

document.querySelector("#checkout").addEventListener("click", getShoppingAmount );
```

**Checkout.html**:

```
<html>
<h1>Checkout</h1>

Total Shopping Amount: <span id="Shopamount" ></span>
<script>
    // GET SUM VIA localStorage
    document.querySelector("#Shopamount").textContent = window.localStorage.getItem("sum");

    // GET SUM VIA query string
    let queryString = document.location.search;
    let sum = queryString.split("=")[1];
    document.querySelector("#Shopamount").textContent = sum;
</script>
```

**[ UPDATED ]** to include another way of passing data between two pages via the query string mechanism as pointed out by @Jonathan Gray

Comment: that is an improper usage of localStorage

Comment: This is just a basic example to get started with the usage of localStorage. Feel free to elaborate on why it is an improper usage, and also to edit the code accordingly @JonathanGray

Comment: Using localStorage to pass data between "pages" is equivalent to storing data in a global variable to pass it between functions. You're introducing the possibility of unforeseen consequences. Even worse you're storing the data on a disk which it never needs to touch. A much better way would be to pass the data using a query-string.

Comment: Nevertheless, the query string solution you mention is also a nice approach. Feel free to add your answer @JonathanGray

Comment: @KostasX can this be done as multiple instances? like If i wanted to do the same thing to get total tax based off sum would it work in the same js file or would I have to make a new one.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in the same JS file. @AsaMurphy

Comment: @KostasX you think you can take a look at my code again? I updated the original question.